# LinearLayout put child at the right side

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout, layout-gravity

I m trying to have a textview and a button in linear layout with horizontal orientation. The textview should appear at the starting and the button should appear at the end. I thought giving gravity right to the button would do the trick but the buttons doesn't move to the right side. I m thinking if I should probably use relative layout?

[image]

```
<\LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/productPriceTextView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Rs 3579.0" 
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buyNowButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="Buy Now" />
<\/LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My way (using a RelativeLayout):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/productPriceTextView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Rs 3579.0"
    />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buyNowButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Buy Now"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

See how I explicitly align the TextView to the Parent's left side and the Button to the Parent's right side

You can then center the TextView vertically in the RelativeLayout, by setting:

```
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

in the TextView itself

---

Newr OS versions may prefer this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/productPriceTextView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:text="Rs 3579.0"
    />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buyNowButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:text="Buy Now"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. @FrankNStein please do you think you could give me your opinion on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25598696/recommended-way-order-to-read-data-from-a-webservice-parse-that-data-and-inse

Answer (score 8):

Try below xml:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/productPriceTextView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Rs 3579.0"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buyNowButton1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="Buy Now" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: this makes the size of the button bigger , I think relative layout suits this case.

Comment: Thank you so much. It is working fine as per my need.

Answer (score 7):

There is a cleaner way to do this, using LinearLayout : just give the left element a width of 0 and a weight of 1, and set the right one's width on wrap_content. And that's it!

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/productPriceTextView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Rs 3579.0" 
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buyNowButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Buy Now" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: it worked well, does it have any performance implications by any chance

Comment: Not that I know of, as it is a simple LinearLayout.

Comment: This produces best results

Answer (score 1):

There are two approach:

1) You can use `RelativeLayout` in which you can drag your `Button` where you want..

2) You can use weight property for `LinearLayout`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/productPriceTextView1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.8"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="Rs 3579.0"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buyNowButton1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:text="Buy Now" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this layout instead..

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
android:id="@+id/productPriceTextView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Rs 3579.0"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />



<Button
android:id="@+id/buyNowButton1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Buy Now"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `android:layout_gravity="end"` to your linear layout to move all the elements to the right

Answer (score 0):

Another simple solution here that doesn't rely on using a `RelativeLayout` is having an empty `view` between both elements using `layout_weight` to make sure it fills the empty space.

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:orientation="horizontal">

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/productPriceTextView1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Rs 3579.0"/>

  <view
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="1" />

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/buyNowButton1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="right"
      android:text="Buy Now" />
</LinearLayout>
```

That way you can achieve what you want by only using a `LinearLayout`, now, I am not sure if this is more efficient than using a `RelativeLayout`. But for me it always feels a bit like an overkill to go for a relative in such a simple layout.

Answer (score 0):

Just add empty view with 0dp width and 1 weight

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/productPriceTextView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Rs 3579.0" 
        />
     <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buyNowButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        
        android:text="Buy Now" />
</LinearLayout>
```